# How to use ripgrep in Ubuntu to search line in a CSV file

Tags: shell, ubuntu, grep, ripgrep

I have a csv file in my home directory as below

```
cat try.csv
val1,val2,val3,val4,val5,val6
10-Jul-19,12604876601113439,Self,abs,Tier-I,30088.5
09-Jul-19,12604876601112397,Self,abs,Tier-I,200590
08-Jul-19,12604876601111807,Self,abs,Tier-I,200590
05-Jul-19,12604876601109069,Self,abs,Tier-I,70206.5
29-May-19,12604876601085648,Self,cdf,Tier-I,70206.5
30-Apr-19,12604876601068094,Self,cdf,Tier-I,130383.5
15-Nov-18,12604876600900949,Self,xyz,Tier-I,71209.46
10-Oct-18,12604876600887501,Self,xyz,Tier-I,79233.06
```

I can use `grep` command to extract the rows having word *'abs'*:

```
grep -w 'abs' try.csv
10-Jul-19,12604876601113439,Self,abs,Tier-I,30088.5
09-Jul-19,12604876601112397,Self,abs,Tier-I,200590
08-Jul-19,12604876601111807,Self,abs,Tier-I,200590
05-Jul-19,12604876601109069,Self,abs,Tier-I,70206.5
```

However I have come across `ripgrep` in https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/ which claims to have similar functionalities of `grep` but performs faster *(my actual csv file is very big with size 30gb so I need for some faster way than `grep`)*

So I installed `ripgrep` with `cargo install ripgrep` and run below code

```
ripgrep -w 'abs' try.csv
```

But I got below error

```
Command 'ripgrep' not found, did you mean:

  command 'sipgrep' from deb sipgrep
  command 'zipgrep' from deb unzip

Try: apt install <deb name>
```

Any pointer to use ripgrep in the correct way will be helpful

Comment: please let us know if it is any faster. Good luck.

Comment: I dont see huge improvement. But I am open to any other option for faster processing of 27gb file

Comment: If you could get the file reorganized so you could use either beginning of line anchor or end-of-line anchor reg-ex (`^` or `$`), that might help a little. Or have it delivered in multiple parts that you can then use `gnuparallel` to run multiple greps. You're not going to get much faster than basic grep, its optimized C code (for 40+ years now). Good luck.

Comment: ripgrep is faster than basic grep in a lot of scenarios. Please see the benchmarks. However, if your file is 27GB and doesn't all fit into memory, then you will likely just be blocked on the speed of your underlying I/O device. ripgrep cannot magically make that faster.

Answer (score 1):

The program is called `ripgrep` but it is invoked by `rg`. All you need to do is:

```sh
rg -w 'abs' try.csv
```